# Create a row with subtotals above data to be added with a Loop through an array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to programmatically format an excel table creating two different subtotals base on changes of values in two specified column (the first and second of the spreadsheet).

I managed to code the routine for the first subtotals but I’m now stuck trying to figure out the second part of the code.

In the second routine I need to create the subtotal row above the data that will be added. I couldn’t manage to insert the calculation in the right row and there is something wrong when I do the loop through the columns included in the array.

Anyone that can see what I’m doing wrong?

Thank you

```
Public Sub SubtotalTable()
Dim RowNumber As Long
Dim RangePointer As Range
Dim RangeTopRow As Range

'Pointing the column to check
Set RangePointer = ActiveSheet.Range("B1")

'Assigning the first row to a range
Set RangeTopRow = Rows(2)

'Assigning to long a variable the number of row from which begin checking
RowNumber = 3

Do
    If RangePointer.Offset(RowNumber).Value <> RangePointer.Offset(RowNumber - 1).Value Then
        Set RangeTopRow = Rows(RowNumber)
        'Call the function to insert the row
        Call InsertRowTotalsAbove(RangePointer.Offset(RowNumber), RangeTopRow, RowNumber)        
    Else
        RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
    End If
        RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Public Function InsertRowTotalsAbove(RangePointer As Range, lastRow As Range, RowNumber As Long)
Dim ArrayColumns() As Variant
Dim ArrayElement As Variant
Dim newRange As Range

'Assigning number of columns to an array
ArrayColumns = Array("D", "E", "F", "G")

Do
    If RangePointer.Offset(RowNumber).Value = RangePointer.Offset(RowNumber - 1).Value Then
        RowNumber = RowNumber - 1            
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNumber + 1, 2).Select
        Set newRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0))
        Rows(newRange.Offset(RowNumber + 1).Row).Insert shift:=xlDown
        newRange.Offset(RowNumber + 1, 0).Value = "Totale" & " " & newRange.Offset(RowNumber + 2, 0)        
        For Each ArrayElement In ArrayColumns
            newRange.Cells(RowNumber, ArrayElement).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(lastRow.Cells(-1, ArrayElement).Address & ":" & RangePointer.Cells(0, ArrayElement).Address))
        Next ArrayElement
    End If    
Loop

End Function
```

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "there is something wrong"?

Comment: Without having a look at your data, I ask you this: is it formatted well? If you format your data so you can use Excel's Tables, it is easier to manipulate and additionally there is a subtotal row built in. As far as this code goes, does it give you an error? If so, what line?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct the calculations are shifted by one column. Instead of starting from the "D" it starts from "E" and also the result is not correct, I do not understand what's adding up.

Comment: @SandPiper It's not giving any error. If can helps I can post the table but I guess that there is nothing wrong with the format. It's a plain table from access

Comment: If you select your data and the column headers, go to Insert->Table, and check the box that says "My Table Has Headers". It will create a ListObject and format the data in pretty blue striped lines. The color is irrelevant and can be changed, but you can go to the Design tab and check the box called "Total Row" under the Table Style Options block. That will be your subtotal.

Comment: @SandPiper Thank you for the suggestion but that's not a option. This is just a piece of code inside a more complex project with the purpose to format several tables each months

Comment: Roger that. So back to the original question: what do you mean there is something wrong? If no error is being thrown, that means you are getting behavior you did not expect. Be more specific in your question about what you expect it to do and what it is actually doing, and if possible where the difference begins. Stepping through with the debugger helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the cause of your first problem (the shift). The second problem (the wrong values) will hopefully be clear once you cleaned up the code.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNumber + 1, 2).Select
Set newRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0))
```

First, as a general best practice never use `select` as it's difficult to debug and can cause significant performance issues. However in this case that's not causing your problem.

Your `newRange` is now the cell `Cells(RowNumber + 1, 2)`, i.e. in column B. (This is way too complicated btw, why not do it in one line `Set newRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNumber + 1, 2)`?)

Anyway, when you later have

```
newRange.Cells(RowNumber, ArrayElement).Value
```

the column is relative to `newRange`. Since newRange is a cell in column B, `newRange.Cells(RowNumber, "A")` is going to be in column B and so on.

My advice would be to use column indices instead and adjust for the shift of 1 by substracting 1 from the column index. However, you should try to clean up your code by using less indirect references. For example using less `Offset`s if you know the actual row number. `Rows(newRange.Offset(RowNumber + 1).Row` would simply be `Rows(2 * RowNumber + 1)` etc.